# Execute bash command with calling subshell $() via ssh with Here Document

Tags: bash, ssh, heredoc, subshell

I try to send command via ssh which looks like this:

```
ssh user@192.168.1.1 "echo $(uname -a)"
```

But my problem is, that `$(uname -a)` part actually create a subshell and executes not on 192.168.1.1 server, but on my system, from which I executed this command.

How can I fix it?

P.S. My actual example involved docker stop all command, which looks like

```
docker stop $(docker ps -q)
```

but I simplified question.

UPDATED:
Sorry, I oversimplify my question. My command use Here Document (because inside command is complex and use a lot of different quotes marks)

```
ssh user@192.168.1.1 <<SSHCOMMAND
  echo $(uname -a)
SSHCOMMAND
```

So Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams solution will not work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found [solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/166778/how-do-i-prevent-bash-substitution) -

```
ssh user@192.168.1.1 <<'SSHCOMMAND'
  echo $(uname -a)
SSHCOMMAND
```

Pretty strange for me, but works, thanks Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams for correct name of this process 'substitution', I couldn't find before :)

Comment: See 'man sh' near the bottom of the section 'Redirections'.  It is all documented there.

Answer (score 7):

Single quotes suppress *all* substitution.

```
ssh user@192.168.1.1 'echo $(uname -a)'
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution works fine, but I added more complex example, which is closer to my actual command.